# How to fix incompatibility between mac os permission of files & folders with our hosting server

Tags: wordpress, permissions, cpanel

Every time I upload my theme folder(WordPress) from my Mac OS to my hosting server(CPanel), I have lots of permission errors and I should fix the permissions again on our server.
Is there any way to fix permission on my Mac OS to be compatible with my server permissions (folders:775 & files:644 )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search found this at macinstruct.

How to Modify Permissions with chmod
For total control over permissions, you can use two Unix commands - ls and chmod - to display permissions and modify them. Assume you want to find a folder’s current permissions and then change them to 755. This would give you as the owner read, write and execute permissions, and everyone else read and execute permissions.

Here’s how to find a folder’s current permissions and change them:

Open the Terminal application.

Once you direct yourself to where your files/folders are located...

Type ls –l, and then press Return. The symbolic permissions of the files and folders in your home directory are displayed, as shown below.

Type chmod 755 foldername, and then press Return. This changes the permissions of the folder to rwxr-xr-x.
When it comes to using the ls and chmod commands, practice makes perfect. Try modifying the permissions on a couple of sample files. If you need more help, use the man command to display the manual pages for these commands (e.g., man ls).